# Bind key in Old SystemV for end-of-line

Tags: bash

I'm on old SystemV unix 2.1
Bash shell of course.
I want to bind the key "end" to end-of-line
the key `^E` works fine

On $HOME/.bashrc I had

```
bind '"\e[3~": delete-char'
bind '"\e[OF": end-of-line'
```

The key "canc-delete" is perfect,the "end-of-line"..doens't work at all.
Why?
Using ctrl+v and pressing end
return

```
^[OF
```

of course `source .bashrc` is given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[` means the same as `\e`, so you should have

```
bind '"\eOF": end-of-line'
```

Your version has one extra `[`.